# Visual Understanding of Vector3.Angle

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, angle

I don't understand the concept of Vector3.Angle in Unity.
Can someone please explain in detail of what it does and how it works?
It would also be really awesome if you could provide some diagrams for me understand it more, visually.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is what a vector is. A vector is a mathematical quantity that has both a magnitude and direction. For the purpose of this question, we don't care about the magnitude but you can think of a vector as an arrow pointing in some direction.

Now, you might be confused how we draw an arrow using only `Vector3(x, y, z)`. While you might more commonly use a Vector3 to represent a point in 3D space, it is of course also used as a vector, as the name suggests. The thing is, if you try to call `Vector3.Angle(transform1.position, transform2.position)` you're going to get some weird results because it's expecting *vectors*, not *positions* even though they use the same object type.

Therefore, you should instead do something like

```
Vector3 direction = transform2.position - transform1.position;
float angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, transform1.forward);
```

`forward` is just a shorthand for a vector along the z-axis, so this would be like looking at an angle in 2D space.

Answer (score 0):

It's very straight forward, Vector3.angle. takes 2 parameters, to and from. Essentially returns the angle that's generated from one position, to another. An example would be var characterDirection would be the "from" parameter, and lets say var enemyPosition would be the "to" parameter, and it will generate an acute angle. Hope this helps, also Unity has a great scripting API you should check it out.

Comment: Yea sorry man. Its these kind of descriptions that makes me uncertain of how it works.
Because ive tested this for myself.
So like, i dont understand how it works.
When i have the first parameter as tansform.position. And i have it at 0, 0, 0. Its 90 degrees.
I dont understand it. And when i change the second parameter the angle doesnt change. I dont get it.